# A-Frame animated texture offset

Tags: aframe

How to animate a texture offset in A-Frame?

I tried

```
<a-entity 
   animation="property: components.material.material.offset; from: 0 0; to: 1 1; dur: 5000;loop: true;" 
   geometry="primitive: cylinder; height: 200; radius: 20; openEnded: true;" 
   material="src: tex.jpg;side: double;shader:flat;"></a-entity>
```

Also tried the properties "**components.material.material.map.offset**" and "**components.material.material.map.offset.x**". The last two result in an error

```
TypeError: s is null
```

My goal is to animate the repeating texture over and obkect in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Animation component works on another component or one of its properties.
https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#api
from the docs:

`Property to animate. Can be a component name, a dot-delimited property of a component (e.g., material.color), or a plain attribute.`

So, this should work:
`animation="property: material.offset; to: 0.2 0.5"`

But it fails, and throws an error. I suspect the reason it is failing is due to the way Aframe is accessing properties of a material component. Color works, which is a different data type than offset (Vector2). I've asked the guys at aframe directly about this.

Here is a glitch I made that shows how to transform a texture, using offset.

`material=" offset: 0.5 0.25"`

https://glitch.com/~texture-offset

if you change the animation component, in line 20, to
`animation="property: material.offset; to: 0 0"`

it fails (renders blank).

But you could make a custom component that used the tick event to call setAttribute on material.offset and animate the texture transform that way.

---

Another approach (if you want more control over all aspects of texture transforms) would be to work directly with THREEjs objects. Below is a glitch that show how to do that
https://glitch.com/~tex-animwave

The animation component is built on anime.js, so you could import that library and have it drive the THREEjs parameters directly.
https://animejs.com/